# Vulkan not running on GT 1030

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a 10 year old computer with a brand new gt 1030. I just installed ubuntu (pristine installation).

I have tried both proprietary drivers and nouveau both error with the message:

```
/build/vulkan-tools-KEbD_A/vulkan-tools-1.2.131.1+dfsg1/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.h:477: failed with ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

When I search that error I find that usually means the card doesn't support vulkan. But nvidia says it does:

https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver

I am running Ubuntu 20.04, I am not sure which stack is being used and I don't know how to check.

Steps to reproduce:
Install ubuntu, install vulkan-utils, run vulkaninfo.

Comment: You've provided no details about what Ubuntu you're using.. if desktop (most likely, but it's best if we're told rather than guessing), if server, which release, and if a LTS, which stack you've chosen to use (as Ubuntu LTS releases have two kernel stack choices).

Comment: What steps do you take to reproduce this error?  Is this the entire error?